# cannot create a single result set oracle joins or subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I have three basic queries that are related to each other and I need a single result set to return.

Simplified:

Query1 (possible return not a show stopper return null):

```
SELECT * FROM monkey WHERE monkey.ENDDATE IS NULL AND monkey.TEMPLATEID = 1
```

Query2 (possible return not a show stopper return null):

```
SELECT * FROM banana WHERE banana.ENDDATE IS NULL AND banana.TEMPLATEID = 1
```

Query3 (must return something):

```
SELECT * FROM tree WHERE tree.TEMPLATEID = 1
```

Query 1 and 2 may or may not return a value (come back null).

The third one will need to return a result (or not) IF the third query returns something I and query 1 or 2 fail I still want to return something.

I can’t do an outer join with 2 queries, because oracle won’t let me the error said… `a.b (+) = b.b and a.c(+) = c.c is not allowed instead turn b+c into a view`.

I think I understand the logical reason, never-the-less I need to return query 3 and maybe query 1, 2 or 1 and 2 along with 3 as a single result set.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do the three queries return the same number and type of columns? If so you can `union` the results, but that may be unlikely with them coming from three tables.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure whether you want one row containing the columns from all three tables, or (up to) three rows, assuming one row matches in each table?

Comment: The queries return different things related to query 3, the premise is that if someting happens and table one and table 2 don't get updated then it doesn't stop the third from returning something based on the template id...also i removed the end date is null from query 3 that was a mistake...

Comment: Will the TEMPLATEID be the same for each query?  That is, if you're looking for `MONKEY.TEMPLATEID=2` you will also be restricting on `BANANA.TEMPLATEID=2`  and `TREE.TEMPLATEID=2` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be hitting ORA-01417. Using made up tables and data as you haven't provided any, or the join conditions, I can get the same effect by trying to outer join `monkey` to both `tree` and `banana` - in a completely contrived way, of course:

```
with banana as (select 'yellow' as colour, 1 as template_id, null as enddate
        from dual),
    monkey as (select 'capuchin' as monkeytype, 1 as template_id, null as enddate
        from dual),
    tree as (select 'tropical' as treetype, 1 as template_id from dual)
select t.treetype, b.colour, m.monkeytype
from tree t, banana b, monkey m
where t.template_id = 1
and b.template_id (+) = t.template_id
and b.enddate (+) is null
and m.template_id (+) = t.template_id
and m.enddate (+) is null
and m.template_id (+) = b.template_id;

Error at Command Line:10 Column:22
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table
01417. 00000 -  "a table may be outer joined to at most one other table"
*Cause:    a.b (+) = b.b and a.c (+) = c.c is not allowed
*Action:   Check that this is really what you want, then join b and c first
           in a view.
```

if you use the 'new' (since 9i, I think) ANSI join syntax, rather the Oracle-specific `(+)` notation, you can do more:

```
with banana as (select 'yellow' as colour, 1 as template_id, null as enddate
        from dual),
    monkey as (select 'capuchin' as monkeytype, 1 as template_id, null as enddate
        from dual),
    tree as (select 'tropical' as treetype, 1 as template_id from dual)
select t.treetype, b.colour, m.monkeytype
from tree t
left join banana b on b.template_id = t.template_id
    and b.enddate is null
left join monkey m on m.template_id = t.template_id
    and m.enddate is null
    and m.template_id = b.template_id
where t.template_id = 1;

TREETYPE COLOUR MONKEYTYPE 
-------- ------ ---------- 
tropical yellow capuchin
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm) for some of the restrictions on `(+)`; Oracle recommend using the ANSI version, though they seem to use their own most of the time in examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that the tables, "monkey", "banana", and "tree" all have different column types, otherwise you can easily obtain what you want using a "UNION" or "UNION ALL" operator.

Also since you haven't shared the table defn. of these tables, I don't know if you have any foreign keys to join these tables or not. SO I am assuming they are completely unrelated.

So with these 2 assumptions....

Here's another way, of returning combined resultsets from different queries.

```
SELECT CURSOR(QRY1), CURSOR(QRY2), CURSOR(QRY3) FROM DUAL;
```

This will give you all three result-sets in one query. But each result-set is a ref-cursor which you'll have to navigate in your application.

If using java, the java type of each of the 3 columns, is a ResultSet, which you'll have to navigate, to get individual query results.

e.g.

```
String qry1= "SELECT * FROM monkey WHERE monkey.ENDDATE IS NULL";
String qry2 = " SELECT * FROM banana WHERE banana.ENDDATE IS NULL AND banana.TEMPLATEID = 1";
String qry3= "SELECT * FROM tree WHERE tree.ENDDATE IS NULL AND tree.TEMPLATEID = 1";

String qry = "SELECT CURSOR("+qry1+"), CURSOR("+qry2+"), CURSOR("+qry3+") FROM DUAL";

ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(qry);

if(rs.next()) { //no while loop necessary, as we are expecting only one row

    ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) rs.getObject(1);
    ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet) rs.getObject(2);
    ResultSet rs3 = (ResultSet) rs.getObject(3);


    while(rs1.next()) {
        // retrive results of qry1
    }

    // same for rs2 and rs3
}
```

Hope that helped.